# Numpy finding the element greater than previous n elements

Tags: python, loops, numpy, iteration, vectorization

I want to identify elements in numpy array which is greater than previous 5 elements starting from index 5. I wrote solution to this problem below with 'for' loop. My question is that how can I solve this like problems without iteration? Is there certain numpy function for this problem?

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([160, 140, 152, 142, 143, 186, 152, 145, 165, 152, 143, 148, 196, 152, 145, 157, 152])
indices = []
for i in range(5, len(values)):
    if np.all(values[(i-5):i]<values[i]):
        indices.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick would be to compute the maximum in a sliding window across the length of the array, excluding the current element and compare against the current element. If the current element is bigger, then we have a winner, else we don't.

To have the sliding max values, we can avail the services of [`Scipy's 1D max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d.html) filter and thus have an implementation like so -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter1d as maxf

def greater_than_all_prev(values, W=5):
    hW = (W-1)//2
    maxv = maxf(values,W, origin=hW)
    mask = values[1:] > maxv[:-1]
    mask[:W-1] = 0
    return np.flatnonzero(mask)+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [336]: values
Out[336]: 
array([160, 140, 152, 142, 143, 186, 152, 145, 165, 152, 143, 148, 196,
       152, 145, 157, 152])

In [337]: greater_than_all_prev(values, W=5)
Out[337]: array([ 5, 12])
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is the fastest one! Should I learn scipy module as well as numpy for data analysis?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov Should be a great idea I think!

Answer (score 1):

Erik Rigtorp posted a nice trick for [Efficient rolling statistics with NumPy](http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html):

> A loop in Python are however very slow compared to a loop in C code.
> Fortunately there is a trick to make NumPy perform this looping
> internally in C code. This is achieved by adding an extra dimension
> with the same size as the window and an appropriate stride:
>
> ```
> def rolling_window(a, window):
>     shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
>     strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
>     return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
> ```

Using this function you can do:

```
winlen = 5

values = np.array([160, 140, 152, 142, 143, 186, 152, 145, 165, 152, 143, 148, 196, 152, 145, 157, 152])

rolling_values = rolling_window(values, winlen + 1)
rolling_indices = np.arange(winlen, values.shape[0])

mask = np.all(rolling_values[:, [-1]] >  rolling_values[:, :-1], axis=1)
indices = rolling_indices[mask]
print(indices)
```

#### Explanation:

`rolling_window` converts the values into an array of the following form:

```
print(rolling_values)
array([[160, 140, 152, 142, 143, 186],
       [140, 152, 142, 143, 186, 152],
       [152, 142, 143, 186, 152, 145],
       [142, 143, 186, 152, 145, 165],
       [143, 186, 152, 145, 165, 152],
       [186, 152, 145, 165, 152, 143],
       [152, 145, 165, 152, 143, 148],
       [145, 165, 152, 143, 148, 196],
       [165, 152, 143, 148, 196, 152],
       [152, 143, 148, 196, 152, 145],
       [143, 148, 196, 152, 145, 157],
       [148, 196, 152, 145, 157, 152]])
```

Each row contains an element (starting with the sixth one) and the previous five elements. Due to the strides trick this representation does not require much more memory than the original array.

Now, we can compare if the last element in each row is larger than the previos elements and look up the corresponding indices.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I actually knew and used striding, but it just didn't come to my mind to use that in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be this:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([160, 140, 152, 142, 143, 186, 152, 145, 165, 152, 143, 148, 196, 152, 145, 157, 152])

prod = np.ones_like(values)
for n in range(1,6):
    prod *= values > np.roll(values, n)
print(prod)
```

If you find a `1` in `prod` at some index, then at this index in `values` your condition of being larger than the previous five elements is fulfilled. You can find those indices with `np.where(prod == 1)`. You should note that `np.roll` wraps around the boundaries of the array.